# Does Han Solo only do this because Leia asked him to do it?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

It seems to me that

> Han only approached Kylo Ren because Leia specifically asked him to bring their son back. And he seemed a bit hesitant to do it.

Maybe the novelization clears this up, by showing his thoughts maybe?

Comment: Who blames her for this?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase it. What I think I meant is "would it still have happened if she didn't ask it?"

Comment: That question would be off topic, as it calls for speculation and opinion.

Comment: I'll edit the question in a minute to make it more objective

Comment: Unless someone who's read the novelization can offer some insight, I don't think there's any non-speculative way to answer this question.

Comment: Not going to post this as the answer because I can't find anything to back this up but (warning spoilers ahead) Ben is Han's kid too. It's not like he didn't care at all and it was just some random dude that Leia asked him to talk to. He was hesitant because he probably knew that the outcome wouldn't be good, but he still had to try, I mean wouldn't anyone want to try and help their kid from becoming the next Darth Vader?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Foster Novelization confirms it - he only did it because Leia asked.

Basically, the ONLY reason he didn't tell her "No, what glitterstream have you been sniffing?" is that he was afraid she would dump him again, permanently.

> **He wanted to laugh derisively. If he did, he knew she might never speak to him again**. “Me? No. If Luke couldn’t reach him, with all his skills and training, how can I?”
>   She was nodding slowly. “Luke is a Jedi. But you’re his father. There’s still light in him. I know it.”

This is confirmed when we hear his thoughts when he's debating whether to confront Ren or not when he actually bumps into him:

> A chance, then, to make it back to the Falcon before everything on this planet went to hell. A chance later for another reunion, on another world. A face swam before his, its features aged but still soft, the voice that emerged from between so-familiar lips biting yet always affectionate. **Forming words that lingered in his thoughts. Forming, at last hearing, a request**.
>   **A request that wouldn’t go away, he knew. It would never go away. He made up his mind**. Instead of retreating, he advanced. Instead of running for safety, he took up the challenge. There was no real choice, he told himself as he advanced to the edge of the walkway. And called out.
>   “Ben!”